# Android with java

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio

there is a snippet of code of an android app (Android Studio) in Java language I tried to understand,there is number 17 as an index of an array as I highlighted the line code in bold , I tried a lot but I couldn't understand what's that number, here is the snippet code

---

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        **if(result == "0")**
        {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Invalid IP address";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
        else
        {
            char[] charArray = result.toCharArray();
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            **if(charArray[17]=='0')**
            {

                CharSequence text = "Invalid Password";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                _logged_in = false;
            }
            **if(charArray[17]=='1')**
            {
                CharSequence text = "You logged in successfully";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                _logged_in = true;
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

---

Thanks in advance

Comment: That means the 18th character of `charArray`, so the 18th character of `result`.

Comment: This is rather poorly done - 2 things stick out.  First, it should be result.equals("0") not result === "0".  Secondly, the two if statements to ascertain success are exclusive and so the second [if(charArray[17]=='1')] should be 'else if' not 'if'.

Comment: Definitely should fix the string things as mentioned. Also it seems like the 18th character of result stores whether or not the login was successful AND whether there was an error with IP addresses. All of this at the end of a AsyncTask I'm guessing. Not my favorite implementation. Result should just be a constant integer or better an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

```
if(result == "0")
```

If you are working with a `String` you should use:

```
   if(result.equals("0"))
```

Also

```
if(charArray[17]=='0')
```

means that `charArray` is an array and you are getting the element with index=17. Pay attention that the first index is 0.